# Adding a custom field to devise invitable invitation BEFORE sending the invite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise-invitable

So I have spent some time now trying to track down the illusive way to add a custom field to the field the "invitee" sends the invitation to.. My app is not a public facing app, and so the human resources department will send the invite upon hiring. However i would like to add basic information about the user being invited, and then they can fill out the non-pertinent info once they sign into the application..

is there a way to do this using a params sanitizer? i have only been able to find

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:accept_invitation, keys: [:fname, :lname, :mobiletel, :password, :password_confirmation, :invitation_token])
```

but I need to do this before the invite is sent out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated here!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I approached it:

```
# config/routes.rb
# Use a custom invitations controller.
devise_for :users, controllers: { invitations: 'users/invitations' }
```

```
# app/controllers/users/invitations_controller.rb
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

  protected

  # Permit the new params here.
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:invite, keys: [:email, :additional_fields, :added_here])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me, although instead of `:invite` I had to use `:accept_invitation`